# access Vuejs app public url without port number | https

Tags: linux, vue.js, https, port, config

Whats up guys, I wanted to launch my website but now am a big step away from it. I dont know how to manage this problem.

I want people to connect to my website without passing a port in the url like this: `www.domain.de`, but if I type this in my browser is not connecting to my website. But if I type in `www.domain.de:80` it is working.

here is my vue.config.js

```
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        hotOnly: false,
        port: 80,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('{myprivatekey}'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('{mycert}')
        },
        public: 'https://localhost'
    }
```

I really hope someone knows what to do so I can launch it today.

Best regards, silliton

Comment: The dev server isn't intended for serving your app in production. You should be using a different server for that.

Comment: thanks mate, I just was new to vue.